# Best way to authorize an USB device in organisation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, usb

I am developing a project where I need to restrict usage of accessing non white listed USB devices in the organization network.

I am using it by checking VID and PID of that USB devices.

Now the problem is that If Suppose I have an **Apple I-pad**, that would have a global VID and PID number. If I'll white List any of the Apple I-Pad then with my current scenario all other Apple I-Pad would be authorized in the network.

Is it a best way to check a USB device from VID and PID number whether that device is white listed in organization network or their is some thing else  better then it.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does asp.net come into picture?

Comment: Because developing that application on asp.net, I don't know which tag would be more suitable here..please guide me..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to vendor and product IDs, USB device descriptor can contain a device serial number. If present, it's supposed to be unique for each individual device with a particular VID/PID combination. This serial number is optional (and some vendors may violate the spec by programming non-unique serial numbers in their devices), so check it first. If you're lucky and devices that you care about do contain serial numbers, you'll be able to use a (VID, PID, serial number) combination to uniquely identify a particular device. The serial number is not usually easy to reprogram, which is a plus for your application.